# CodeIgniter MVC and Looping through a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to create a iterate through a row in a MySQL table in one of my CodeIgniter projects, how could I "loop" through the table? Is it just a simple for loop like in other languages?

EDIT:

The answer is as followed:

```
$query = $this->db->get('mytable'); // select table "mytable" from database

foreach ($query->result() as $row) { // loop thru table and access each row's field 
                                     // by using $row->fieldname


}
```

Comment: The best thing to do would be [read the database documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/index.html).

Comment: It completely applies here, you have asked how to connect to the database, select data from it, and then 'do some stuff'… and possibly, create the table too?

Comment: The documentation explains how to do that stuff, it's pretty clear and there are plenty of other questions on SO that can tell you how to do this

Comment: @Dan The documentation does not really clearly explain how to loop through the row in each table (not that I would expect it to).

Comment: You don't need to loop through the rows and you shouldn't.  And if that's the only part of your question that isn't clear then why are you asking about 4 different things?  Create your array and use `update_batch`.  Looping through is bad practice as it will execute many more queries.

Comment: @Dan I'm only asking about one thing which is "iterating through a MySQL table" (see title) -- everything else that was provided is simply for context. :)

Comment: You don't iterate through the table, you create a virtual table by querying your DB than loop through your result using PHP.

Comment: @Bob, I was just trying to be helpful.  Re-read my comments, no need to get defensive.  And FYI I only have one vote so clearly others agree that this question could be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this

```
//$this->db->limit(10); // Optional if you want to limit, read about it
$result = $this->db->get('server'); //return all rows

foreach ($result as $row) {
    $row->status = 'inactive'; // change value of status attribute or whatever
    $this->db->update('server', $row)
}
```

Or maybe use `$this->db->update_batch();` to update a stack of rows at one time.

I encourage you to read the CI [database class documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#update) too.

Another suggestion, is to do all the business logic inside a model instead of a controller. But it's a matter of personal preference maybe.

Comment: Not great practice to query within foreach loop. better to use update_batch

Comment: Well, to add more context to the question I am looking to grab a server IP from each row, check if the server is online, and depending on that result update a column called "status".

Comment: @Bob In this case, you have to loop through each row as I stated in my answer.